# Java PreparedStatement splits my String param value when it contains semicolon or some special characters

Tags: java, prepared-statement, truncate

I am trying to insert a comment that the user can write but psst.setString splits the comment when it contains some special characters

```
String comment = "0asd:sdas=de?asd¡asd/asd*sad-sdf<dfsd>fsdf1;fs2";
PreparedStatement psst = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT);
psst.setString(1, comment);
```

I really need to insert all the String comment including all the special characters as equals and semicolon

Comment: "psst.setString splits the comment when it contains some special characters"—What exactly do you observe?

Comment: I might suggest that the `INSERT` statement be edited into the question. Also, following @khelwood, how are you observing the issue? Are you retrieving it, looking directly in the DB?